# Date Format Gives Wrong Result

Tags: java

I'm trying a code in java to convert a String into Date but I'm getting the output wrong.
Can you please help me out to sort out it.

Here is my java code

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class My {

public static void main( String[] args ) {

    String textDate = "31/12/2015";
    Date actualDate = null;

    SimpleDateFormat yy = new SimpleDateFormat( "MM/dd/yy" );
    SimpleDateFormat yyyy = new SimpleDateFormat( "MM/dd/yyyy" );

    try {
        actualDate = yy.parse( textDate );
    }
    catch ( ParseException pe ) {
        System.out.println( pe.toString() );
    }

    System.out.print( textDate + " enhanced:  " );
    System.out.println( yyyy.format( actualDate ) );
}
}
```

Output I got:

31/12/2015 enhanced:  07/12/2017

Comment: you probably mean dd/MM/yyyy

Answer (score 2):

The date you are trying to parse is not in Month/Day/2 digit year format.You need something like

```
SimpleDateFormat yy = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd/MM/yyyy" );
```

**or** change the `String` like

```
String textDate = "12/31/15";
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `SimpleDateFormat yy = new SimpleDateFormat( "MM/dd/yy" );` to `SimpleDateFormat yy = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");`

Answer (score 0):

The sequence of your code is wrong. You cannot parse `dd/MM/yyyy` to `dd/MM/yy`, so you have to use `yyyy.parse(textDate)` at first and use `yy.format(actualDate)` later to get `31/12/15`.